# String Conversion Error "String index out of range" in python

Tags: python, string, integer

Hello I'm asking about the conversion issue with strings and integers.

I have a piece code that requires the conversion between strings and integers but I just can't get it to work, I wonder if anyone could help me. I receive `String index out of range` error.

Here is the code

```
def ISBN(bc):
   total = 0
   up = 0
   down = 11
   for x in range(10):
      sbc = str(bc)
      ibc = int(sbc[up])
      total += (ibc * down)
      #total += (int(sbc[up])*down)
      up += 1
      down -+ 1
   mod = (total % 12)
   if mod == 10:
      total = "x"
      print ("The ISBN book code is: " + bc + total)

w = 0
while w == 0:
     a = int(input("Please input the 10 digit book number:\n"))
     b = str(a)
     if len(b) == 9:
        ISBN(a)
     else:
        print ("Sorry book code not 10 digits long")
     restart = input("Would you like to use the book code changer again?\n")
     restart = restart.lower
     if restart == "yes" or restart == "y":
        print ("--------------------------------------------------\n")
     elif restart == "no" or restart == "n":
        print ("Thank you for using the ISBN book code changer\n")
        w = 1
```

Comment: what is the point of `a = int(input("Please input the 10 digit book number:\n"))
    b = str(a)`?

Comment: define `can't get it to work` ?

Comment: `down -+ 1` what is that supposed to do?

Comment: Also, your indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if len(b) == 9:
```

This should be 10.

```
mod = (total % 12)
```

This should be 11.